# How to use own element file for flash instead of Bootstrap-ui's default, CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4, cakephp-bootstrap-ui

I am using [bootstrap-ui](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui) plugin for Form but it automatically loads flash. I want to use my own element file for Success/Error/Warning etc but **bootstrap-ui** automatically uses its default.ctp element for rending flash message.

So how can I use my own element files for displaying the flash message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the flash template on app level, like any other plugin template:

```
src/Template/Plugin/BootstrapUI/Element/Flash/default.ctp
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Overriding Plugin Templates from Inside Your Application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application)**